# Crash when presenting modal view controller

Tags: iphone, core-data, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app I have a function that presents a modal view controller when a bar button is pressed. Sometimes I have to call the same function progrmatically. But, whenever I have to present the view programatically, it crashes. I have determined that this is the line of code that makes it crash.

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And I get the error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Website''
```

even though I am not inserting a new object into my entity.

EDIT:
Here is the function that is called programatically and when the bar button is pressed.

```
- (void) presentController {
WebController *webController = [[WebController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];
webController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
webController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:webController animated:YES];
[webController release];
 }
```

And this is code where the error occurs.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController_;
}

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
*/
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Website" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return fetchedResultsController_;
```

}

Edit: I am calling the function `presentController` from the appDelegate when my application resumes from the background state, so I tried calling the same function in my viewController's `viewDidLoad` function, and it does not crash.

Comment: You should include the entire error message. NSInternalInconsistencyException covers a lot of possibilities.

Comment: We'll need to see more of the code you use to call programatically. The problem is going to be hidden somewhere in that code, because you say that is the difference between it working and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `NSNotificationCenter` to send a message to my viewController to tell it to call the method `presentController` which works when sending the notification from my appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are initializing the controller before you try to present it?

Also, make sure all your outlets are connected correctly if you're using a nib.

Comment: I am calling the exact same function that is called when the bar button is pressed, except it always crashes when I call it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fragment of the error message, the problem is with a line that contains the:

```
+[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
```

... method.

Most likely, it's were you get the entity to provide an entity for a fetch request.

Comment: It does say that the error is in that line when it crashes, but I do not see why, because the error is in the viewController that presents the other viewController, and not the one being presented.

Comment: Don't impose your logic on the evidence. The error is where it is. You have to at least understand the error and the code where it occurs before you can exclude it. In any case, we can't help you without seeing the actual code around the line that fails.

Comment: This line doesn't insert anything but instead gets an entity description from the model. It can fail if it finds no entity or hits overlapping entities and for other reasons.